# Does this Array.new in a loop create a memory leak?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I know how I'd do this in C++, but in Ruby, I'm not so sure. This is basically the structure that I'm working with (except that instead of integers, I have 2 element arrays contained within the array *data*.)

```
data = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

while true do
    wrong = Array.new
    data.each do |d|
        print "Guess: "
        guess = gets
        if guess.strip.to_i == d
            puts "Correct!"
        else
            puts "Sorry, the right answer is #{ d }."
            wrong << d
        end
    end

    if wrong.length == 0
        break
    else
        data = wrong
    end
end
```

Am I creating a memory leak by **Array.new** in each loop? Is there an alternative approach that is more efficient?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to start with a list of numbers and have the user guess until they successfully guess each number, then end, or is it something else?

Comment: The example code is exactly that, making the user get them all right until ending. But the basic question is, I have a container, I take some things from it sequentially and keep doing that until it's empty. The approach I'm taking is to put what needs to be kept until the next loop into another container. With each loop, I should swap those containers. I know how to do that in C++, but in Ruby it's a little more opaque for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby allows parallel assignment, so swapping the values of `data` and `wrong` is as easy as

```
data, wrong = wrong, data
```

You aren't creating a memory leak by calling `Array.new` because ruby has automatic garbage collection, so it will delete the old arrays once the program no longer holds a reference to them.

Comment: Correction: it will delete old arrays _at an unspecified point in the future after no live references exist_.

Answer (score 1):

No, Ruby has a garbage collector. The basic design of a garbage collector is that objects are checked to see if they have gone out of scope like your "wrong" variable, and, if not referenced by another object are marked to be deleted (freed).

Ruby and other languages now have more complex garbage collectors and those who work on them for a living can poke holes in the simple explanation I gave, but this is the basic idea.